# Keyboard @ sign missing

Tags: keyboard

I cannot type the `@` sign using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.  I get `"` instead.
I have tried all sorts of language selection. Why do none of the English selection work. 
Setting up email is impossible with no `@` sign!

Comment: Then what do you get when you type `"` key from your middle row? It would be interchanged. I had the same problem.. It seems that you are using `English UK` as Keyboard Layout. Try to change it to `English US`

Comment: Could be a german layout, if it is the @ is on Alt+Gr + q

Answer (score 2):

**A short description**

- Open `Keyboard Layout` from `System Settings` (or search in dash)
- Go to <kbd>Layout</kbd>tab
- Click <kbd>+</kbd> in down-left
- Add `English US` (you can use `keyboard icon` there to check the layout)
- Push it on top (or remove `English UK`). Get more help from pictures.

Keyboard Layout Window:
[image: image1]

Keyboard Layout US:
[image: image2]

- That's it..

Reply for further assistance..

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Alt+Gr</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> instead of <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>